# How does a compiler resolve addresses of structure members?

Tags: c++, c

I am little bit confused about the memory organization of a structure compared to an array. Array elements can be accessed by memory address of the first element in an array and offset to desired index. Now how is the address of a structure member evaluated by the compiler?

```
struct name
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
    struct name *ptr,pt,p;

    p.a=4;
    p.b=4.5;
    ptr=&pt;
    ptr->a=5;
    ptr->b=10.5;
    return 0;
}
```

How does the compiler know, where to store value of member `a` in a structure variable `p` and how does the compiler evaluate the offset and address for member `b`

In the second case, `ptr` contains a reference to the structure variable `pt`.
How does the compiler know the memory addresses of the members.

Comment: What do you mean pt.now? I don't such in the code example. BTW, the compiler just remebers each members offset relative to the beginning of the struct, which is determined by the ABI of the environment.

Comment: its not pt.now, its just structure variable pt

Comment: If `p` is at memory location 100, and ints are 4 bytes, then `p.a` is at memory location 100, and `p.b` is at memory location 104.

Comment: Then if ptr is at 120 , code stores 100 in ptr starting at memory location 120 . ptr->a is at : {address stored at #120} + 4 == 100 + 4 == 104

Comment: @Sneftel i know that but if i want to print p.b then how its memory address will be evaluated by compiler? will compiler store those references somewhere?

Comment: It will take the address of `p` (relative to the stack pointer, since `p` is on the stack), add four to it, then print the value at the resultant address.

Comment: "[struct members] can be accessed by memory address of the [struct] and offset to desired [member]"

Comment: @Sneftel "p.b is at memory location 104" -- not necessarily; it's possible for `float` to have an alignment > 4.

Comment: " p.b then how its memory address will be evaluated by compiler" -- `(char*)&p + offsetof(struct name, b)` "will compiler store those references somewhere" -- it stores the *constant* offsets in a compile-time table. The binary code that makes the reference uses the offset in its address computation (usually the offset is encoded into the binary instruction). There's no need to save the offset in memory.

Comment: @JimBalter Technically possible, but nonexistent in practice. Concreteness is important too.

Comment: "How does the compiler know, where to store value of member a in a structure variable p" --the first member must be at the beginning of the struct, so `&p.a == &p` " how does the compiler evaluate the offset and address for member b" -- the offset is calculated by adding up the lengths of the previous members and whatever padding is necessary. Members don't have addresses by themselves, only relative to the address of some struct instance.

Comment: @Sneftel As a friend of mine says, no good deed goes unpunished. I pointed out a valid issue. You were concrete about the size of an int, and such concreteness is due for the float alignment as well. And its educational to point this out, since it could have been a double, or an architecture you're not familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At compile time, the compiler knows the size of a `struct` and the offsets to its members.
For your `struct name`, the compiler figures out the following information.

1. Size of `struct name`
2. The layout of the member data
3. The offset of `a`, which is zero and offset of `b`, which is non-zero.

The layout of `struct name` might look something like:

```
   <--- Size of struct ---------------->

   +-----------------+-----------------+
   |                 |                 |
   +-----------------+-----------------+

   ^
   |
   Address of ptr

   ^                 ^
   |                 |
   offset of a (0)   offset of b (non-zero)
```

Given the address a pointer points to a `struct name`, the compiler knows exactly how much to offset to get to member `a` and how much to offset to get to member `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler knows the memory of the struct's members because the compiler organises the struct itself. It figures out which bits should go where. Whenever a member is accessed the compiler needs to know the entire struct's definition, this is why, so it knows where the bits and pieces are. As to what the actual offsets are, well that depends on how the compiler wants to do it.

If you NEED to know the offsets, read about `offsetof` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Answer (score 1):

When you run this, program allocates 8 byte for p (4 for int, 4 for float). Address of member 'a' begins from the address of p. In second case you are directly assigning the address of pt to ptr, that means you are assigning the address of 'a' to ptr.

Comment: Please don't hardcore type sizes that are platform dependant into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the compiler know the memory addresses of the members.

Because it *allocates* them in the first place. It's entirely the compiler's decision. In the symbol table, each member is accompanied by its type, its size, and its offset from the start if the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol table that the compiler uses, has information about each element in a struct such as size and data type. coz structs are statically alloc'd, elements are packed together and their offsets are determined by each elements size. The address of the struct is the address of its first element

ptr->b=10.5;  is an implicit pointer arithmetic using address of struct and size of element 'a' to determine location of element 'b'.